# active directory dns domain name and external website (same domain)

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, url

When our AD domain was originally created, it was named somedomain.com.
The problem we've been having, is with the website for somedomain.com, being hosted elsewhere on the net.  Computers on our internal Lan, joined to the domain somedomain.com, believe the website for somedomain.com to be from the local server.  We have been manually updating host files to solve this issue but wondered if there was a way to update dns record on somedomain.com active directory dns, to do the re-routing for us (easier then going to each workstation and editing the host file every couple of years.  If I had of installed the domain originally, I definitely would have named it somedomain.local but what's done is done.

Answer (score 0):

Tell your users to access the website via `www.somedomain.com` instead of `somedomain.com`. Then create a DNS zone named `www.somedomain.com` and create an "apex" A record in the zone for the ip address of the website.